# Thread still runs when flask server exits

Tags: python, multithreading, flask

As titles describe, I create a separate thread to do a long task in `Flask`.

```
import schedule
import time

start_time = time.time()


def job():
    print("I'm working..." + str(time.time() - start_time))


def run_schedule():
    while True:
        schedule.run_pending()
        time.sleep(1)
```

When I press `Ctrl + c` to terminate the server, the thread still `prints`. **How can I stop the thread when server exits?**

Comment: have you tried __ctrl+z__

Comment: then add your code in try except, handle keyboard interruption and on that event pause/stop your thread

Comment: **ctrl+z ** can work but is there any other way such as to check main_thread alive.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may want to set your thread as [daemon](https://docs.python.org/3/library/threading.html#threading.Thread.daemon).

A thread runs until it ends by itself or it is explicity killed.

A daemon thread runs with the same conditions and if at least one other non-daemonic thread is running: this means that if you end your main thread and no other threads are running, all daemonic thread will end as well.

if you're using threading module, you may set the thread as daemonic by changing his boolean:

```
import threading
your_thread.daemon = True
```

if you're using thread module, it should be one of the kwargs

Comment: Thanks for your answer.